# Notifications about unread messages (node.js + sockets.io)

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a system of personal messages between users on node.js sockets.io, is now faced with the problem that I do not understand how to make the notification about unread messages. Let's say, how to determine what a user who has received a message read this message, and how to make a notification message if the user is not in correspondence?
ps Chat History and active dialogs are stored in mysql.

Comment: What is your specific question that conforms to the help page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Assume if the user has an open socket, and the message has been sent, then when the user clicks in a certain area of the page (perhaps the send message box?), an onClick event is fired to notify the server the user has received the message.

If the user is not on the webpage, there's not a way to contact them through sockets.io.